# Why can't I pass in java an array of short to method accepting array of int?

Tags: java, arrays, parameter-passing

I have a method, that accepts int[] parameter. I want to pass it an array of shorts. But all I get is "incompatible types: short[] cannot be converted to int[]". Why is that?
an example:

```
short[] arr = new short[2];
arr[0] = 8;
arr[1]=9;
example(arr);

example(int[] anArray){
}
```

As far as I know, short to int is just widening, so it should be typecasted automatically, shouldn't it? 
How to pass it then?
Thanks.

Comment: You've already got some good Java-specific answers to your question.  But the fact that you _thought_ that `short[]` and `int[]` would be related to each other because `short` and `int` seem to be related is perfectly reasonable. If you want to know (way) more about these kinds of questions, start at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science).

Comment: Technically, Java could probably be made to handle this since arrays are (almost) full-fledged objects and hence the operations to read/write an array element are aware (or could be) of the actual array element type.  So at least part of the answer is that C can't handle the same scenario, and Java is modeled after C.  Whether such a change would be good or bad is hard to judge.  (But it's never going to change in Java -- perhaps some follow-on language.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that, because a `short[]` is not an `int[]`.  Also, a `short` is not an `int`, it's just that Java allows a primitive widening conversion to allow a `short` to be widened to an `int`.  However, there is no such primitive widening conversion for arrays of primitive types.

That forces a few core Java APIs to accept many different types of primitive arrays, such as [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28byte%5b%5d%29), which has overloads for many different types of primitive arrays.

If you'd like to do the same thing to a `short[]` that you've already done to an `int[]`, you must provide an overloaded method, such as `example(short[] anArray)`.

The [JLS, Section 5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1), specifies all types of conversions, and specifically disallows those not listed in 5.1.12, "Forbidden Conversions":

```
> Any conversion that is not explicitly allowed is forbidden.
```

Conversions between types of primitive arrays are not listed, so they're not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, arrays are object, as soon as an array of short doesn't extend array of ints it can't be passed as argument.

In other words, array of short IS-not-A array of int.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix short with int just with scalar primitives, this is named widening, by example you can do:

```
short x = 4;
int y = x;
```

Without problems.

The widening according the reference is possible just with scalar types not with arrays.

> 22 specific conversions on primitive types are called the narrowing
>   primitive conversions:
>
> short to byte or char
>
> char to byte or short
>
> int to byte, short, or char
>
> long to byte, short, char, or int
>
> float to byte, short, char, int, or long
>
> double to byte, short, char, int, long, or float
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion may lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision and
>   range.
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion from double to float is governed by
>   the IEEE 754 rounding rules (§4.2.4). This conversion can lose
>   precision, but also lose range, resulting in a float zero from a
>   nonzero double and a float infinity from a finite double. A double NaN
>   is converted to a float NaN and a double infinity is converted to the
>   same-signed float infinity.
>
> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T
>   simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number
>   of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of
>   information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause
>   the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input
>   value.
>
> A narrowing conversion of a char to an integral type T likewise simply
>   discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of
>   bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of
>   information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause
>   the resulting value to be a negative number, even though chars
>   represent 16-bit unsigned integer values.

for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3